# AbstractRoutingDataSource :- Importance of Thread Bound Transaction Context for lookup key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am implementing **AbstractRoutingDataSource** in our project. From what i read

> AbstractRoutingDataSource is an abstract data source implementation
>   that routes getConnection() calls to one of various target DataSources
>   based on a lookup key. The latter is **usually (but not necessarily)**
>   determined through some thread-bound transaction context.

What I am wondering is ,what is the advantage of using a thread bound transaction context to determine the lookup key? When is it ideal to use such a method. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, Bound Threads can change the attributes of the underlying lightweight process. and Lightweight processes are not cached when the bound threads exit.

In Scheduling Context; Bound threads for System Scope and Unbound threads are Process Scope. [Docs Oracle, 2010]

System Scope: compete for CPU with other system threads (such as Kernel Threads).

Process Scope: compete for the CPU within the current process.